# Shuffle a row-column block within a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to know how one would go about shuffle in-place the values in a specified "rectangle" of values in a DataFrame. For example, say I'd like to shuffle the values in the rectangle of data defined by columns 4 to 7 AND rows 12 to 18, inclusive. The idea is to scramble the values in those cells WITHOUT affecting the values outside the rectangle.

Comment: can you show us an example of what you are talking about with a sample dataframe and expected output?

Comment: Is the shuffling done along a specific axis or are all the values shuffled

Answer (score 0):

You could use `numpy.random.shuffle()` on the underlying NumPy array:

> Modify a sequence in-place by shuffling its contents.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20).reshape(5, 4))

np.random.shuffle(df.values[1:3, 1:3])

df  # see [[9, 10], [5, 6]]

    0   1   2   3
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   9  10   7
2   8   5   6  11
3  12  13  14  15
4  16  17  18  19
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use `sample` with `frac=1`, first I "slice" my dataframe to only get the shape I am scrambling, then reshape that dataframe slice to 1-D, then call sample method with 100% fraction, and reshape back to original and copy back into the original dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100).reshape(5,-1))
print(df)
```

Input df:

```
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
0   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
1  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39
2  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59
3  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79
4  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99

#Shuffle first region columns 4 to 7    
df.iloc[:, 4:8] = (df.iloc[:,4:8].stack().sample(frac=1)
                     .set_axis(df.iloc[:, 4:8].stack().index, inplace=False)
                     .unstack())

#Shuffle second region columns 12 to 18
df.iloc[:, 12:19] = (df.iloc[:,12:19].stack().sample(frac=1)
                       .set_axis(df.iloc[:, 12:19].stack().index, inplace=False)
                       .unstack())

print(df)
```

Output df:

```
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
0   0   1   2   3   7  47  65  46   8   9  10  11  18  75  32  73  34  56  37  19
1  20  21  22  23  66  24   4  67  28  29  30  31  92  55  54  97  76  93  74  39
2  40  41  42  43  26  45  27  25  48  49  50  51  12  17  16  38  98  57  96  59
3  60  61  62  63  86  84   6   5  68  69  70  71  14  78  15  53  77  35  94  79
4  80  81  82  83  85  64  87  44  88  89  90  91  95  33  36  52  13  58  72  99
```